# Best approach to use Volley

Tags: android, networking, android-volley

What is the best way to use volley? First I used volley as they provided so sometime it throws

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException because the activity has been finish till the response from volley return.
```

So I went online and find a solution using event bus. So right know I am using event bus, register a event on `onResume` and `unregister` it on `onPause`, and on `onResponse` post the registered event.

But I want some generic and better approach.

PS: There is also a library doing the same thing `OttoVolleyDoneRight` I don't want to use that too.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a singleton instance of Volley - which holds all volley parts there (such as RequestQueue). You should init this singleton as part of your application object (or event as part of your main activity, and then destroy it in onDestroy).

Here's a sample of how to create a Volley singleton:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

I don't think that working with events and volley is correct. You should have a concrete listener for each request you make. What you can do is simple: Create a class (or an inner static class) that implements Volley Listener/ErrorListener and holds your activity in a WeakReference - once callbacks from volley are called just check if your activity reference still exists and do what you want. If it doesn't exist then it was probably was closed (and GC picked up the WeakReference).

This way you avoid memory leaks (leaking the activity) and handle your callbacks correctly.

** I don't know what your app is doing but I'm pretty sure that you don't really need to handle network callbacks in your activity but rather in some adapter you have (of a ListView for example).

Pass a new instance of this listener to Volley as a callback.

```
public class MyImageListener extends implements Response.Listener<T>, Response.ErrorListener {
private WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;
private final String mUrl;

public MyImageListener(String url, Activity activity) {
    mUrl = url;
    mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Activity activity = mActivity.get();
    if (activity != null) {
        // Activity is alive, do what you need with it        
    }
}

@Override
public void onResponse(T result) {
    Activity activity = mActivity.get();
    if (activity != null) {
        // Activity is alive, do what you need with it        
    }   
}
```

}

Cheers!